# user-runtime-dir@0 error

Tags: systemd, rhel

systemd service user-runtime-dir@0 Error in journalctl

```
sudo journalctl -xe -u user-runtime-dir@0

-- Unit user-runtime-dir@0.service has begun shutting down.
Jul 14 08:00:12 systemd-user-runtime-dir[2660105]: Failed to remove runtime directory /run/user/0 (after unmounting): Permission denied
Jul 14 08:00:12 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@0.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 14 08:00:12 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
```

But ownership of /run/user/0 is set correctly as below shown

```
$ sudo ls -ls /run/user/0
total 0
0 srw-rw-rw-. 1 root root  0 Jul 14 08:00 bus
0 drwx------. 2 root root 40 Jun 23 02:50 gnupg
0 srw-rw-rw-. 1 root root  0 Jul 14 08:00 pipewire-0
0 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 80 Jul 14 08:00 systemd
```

Then why it got error "Failed to remove runtime directory /run/user/0 (after unmounting): Permission denied" ? any hints are more than welcome!